# Linking MBProgressHUD to my project

Tags: iphone, ios, mbprogresshud

I am trying to link MBProgressHUD to my project and following this simple tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uiactivityindicatorview_mbprogresshud/.

When I linking my MBProgressHUD, I receive this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBProgressHUD", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Not sure how to solve this error. Need some guidance.

Comment: Make sure `MBProgressHUD.m` is listed under Project->Build Phases->Compile Sources

Comment: Add as a solution.. It worked for me.. I will accept yours as an answer... Thanks for the quick help...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Select your project from project navigator (Which shows at top in your project navigator).
2. Select your application under the target.
3. Select Build Phase.
4. Select Compile Source.
5. Click on + button then select and Add MBProgressHUD.m